# Firefox offloads tab after a short time - how to adjust the time?

Tags: firefox

I have earlier used the plugin Dormancy which offloads a tab when it is been idle for more than X minutes.

Firefox on my laptop does this automatically - no need to install Dormancy, which is nice. But I cannot find where I adjust the time (it feel like 5 minutes, but I need it to be more like 15).

```
$ uname -a
Linux travel 5.15.0-39-lowlatency #42-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 10 12:00:27 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Firefox: 101.0.1 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be [the tab unloading feature added in Firefox 93](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unload-inactive-tabs-save-system-memory-firefox). The linked knowledge base article doesn't say much about configuring it other than disabling it:

> Note: If you want to disable the Tab Unloading feature, you can set the preference `browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory` to false in the Firefox Configuration Editor (`about:config` page).

However, searching for `unload` in `about:config` shows what seems to be a related knob `browser.tabs.min_inactive_duration_before_unload`:

[image]

The default value is 600000, which I assume is in milliseconds (so = 10 minutes). Maybe try setting it to 900000.